# How to configure iptables to pass data from net interface to bridge?

Tags: iptables, linux-networking, openstack

I am building an openstack all-in-one environment in a CentOS7.4 machine. For some reason I have only one network interface(eth0) and one ip address, so I created a linux bridge(br0), and forwarded datas to eth0 using iptables command:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s {bridge virtual ip} -j SNAT --to {eth0 ip}
```

But it seems not work.

When I ping to 8.8.8.8 from br0 and run tcpdump, I can see that datas can be forwared to eth0 and be sent to 8.8.8.8, but when datas are sent back to eth0, they can not be forwarded to br0.

`Ip forwarding`, `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables` and `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables` are set to 1.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

To forward NATed request, you should enable Masquerading in iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

More details could be found in [documentation](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/postrouting-ipmasquerading.html).

Comment: I finally found the root cause. It's because I installed openstack in one machine, and the iptables rules in controller node was conflict with the ones in compute node.